# Given a list of comparisons, sort items with as few additional comparisons as possible

Tags: algorithm, sorting, time-complexity, graph-theory, directed-acyclic-graphs

You have `n` items `x[0], ..., x[n-1]`. Beforehand, you're given a list of several comparisons `c[0], ..., c[k]` for those items (e.g. `c[0] = (x[0] < x[4])`, `c[1] = (x[3] > x[7])`, etc.).

The objective is to sort the items by requesting **as few additional comparisons** as possible.

For example, if `c` contains all the pairwise comparisons, then you don't need to request any additional ones to be able to sort the list. If `c` contained nothing, then you'd request `O(n*log(n))` additional comparisons to perhaps quicksort the items. But if `c` contained something in between, how could we smartly leverage those existing comparisons to guide the extra comparisons we request?

Computation time doesn't matter (so long as it's sub-exponential). All that matters is the algorithm requests roughly the fewest additional comparisons.

Vaguely, I have an idea about constructing a DAG from the comparisons in `c`, and then doing a [topological sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting) for the DAG to get a partial ordering, but I'm not sure where to go from there.

Comment: Given a list of n items and the results of no comparisons between them, the minimum number of comparisons needed to sort them is, I believe, still an open problem. As a result, I'm not sure you're going to be able to get an exact solution to this problem in any reasonable amount of time. Are you okay with an approximation?

Comment: Does it need to ask for all of the comparisons before getting the result of any of them?

Comment: @templatetypedef yeah, of course. I don't want the exact minimum number of comparisons. Just roughly on the order of what's optimal.

Comment: @hobbs You can use every comparison as soon as you ask for it, and dynamically ask for the next one. That being said, the alternative is an interesting question: you have to ask for all the extra comparisons at once. I wonder what the answer is in that case....

Answer (score 0):

Further ideas about the DAG representation:

1. You're not done if your graph has more than one component.
2. You're not done if your graph has more than one node with 0 in-degree or more than one node with 0 out-degree.
3. The [transitive reduction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transitive_reduction) of the graph should be linear — that is, if any node in the transitive reduction has in-degree or out-degree of more than 1, you're not done.
4. Equivalent to #3, there should be no [antichains](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antichain) of more than one element.

I'm assuming that you don't have to choose all of your comparisons in advance, but that graph operations are cheap relative to comparisons (maybe the comparisons require running an experiment, or slow external communication). Then it seems like this would be a decent approach:

1. Identify components.
2. For each component, get all of the antichains of more than one element, and do enough comparisons to sort all of the elements of each antichain (you can use any conventional sorting algorithm here; by definition, we have no useful prior information about antichains, so it's like sorting a random list), adding the edges as you discover them. When this is complete, the transitive reduction of each component should equal its toposort, which will be unique — that is, you've reduced each component to a sorted list.
3. Take components pairwise and "merge sort" them by comparing the smallest elements of the two components to each other, "popping" off the smaller of the two to the end of a new component, and repeating. If one component becomes empty, the remaining items of the other one can be tacked on to the end with no more comparisons. I suspect that repeatedly merging the two smallest components would be optimal for this stage; when there's only one component left, you're done.

Comment: no idea what language or libraries you're using, but networkx at least has an "antichains" method on DAGs.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is [Karzanov and Khachiyan (1991)](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF00385809) (randomized), and [Kahn and Kim (1995)](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S002200008571077X) (improved and deterministic).

Both are on the order of optimal `O(log(E(P)))`, where `E(P)` is the total number of permutations of the items that satisfy your list of comparisons `c`.

I'll quickly go over the randomized algorithm here. Here's how you choose the next comparison to make:

1. Generate `n` sample permutations of the items that satisfy the comparisons via the RandWalk algorithm
2. Assign each item an average rank `r_i` based on its average index over the samples
3. Choose to compare two items whose difference in average rank is less than 1.

The RandWalk algorithm is as follows

1. Do a topological sort to get an ordering `x_1, ..., x_n` of the items that satisfies the comparisons `c`.
2. To get the next sample, repeat `n` times:
3. choose an index `i` uniformly from 1 to `n-1`. If `x_i < x_(i+1)` is not implied by your comparisons `c` (no direct path between them), then swap `x_i` and `x_(i+1)`.
4. the ordering you're left with will be 1 sample ordering that's approximately uniformly chosen from all possible orderings that satisfy `c`.